# Playing multiple sounds in WPF app from embedded resources

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, embedded-resource

I have this code running on a button click:

```
MediaPlayer myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
myPlayer.Open(new Uri("MySound.wav", UriKind.Relative));
myPlayer.Play();
```

Works fine. If I click multiple times I get multiple instances of the sound playing. The sound file is sitting next to the executable.

Now, can I maintain this functionality (multiple instances of sounds playing) but have my sounds embedded in the assembly?

I tried adding the sound to the project and setting the Build Action to Embedded Resource and then created a stream to the data like so:

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyAppNamespace.MySound.wav");
```

The stream is good but then I noticed that the Open method of System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer cannot accept a stream but only a Uri.

Can I create a Uri from my stream or is there any other way to get my sound files playing simultaneously whilst still being embedded?

Comment: I tried SoundPlayer (as used in that other post) but this can only handle one sound at a time.

Comment: Then please update your question, adding that you've tried it.